# How to get substring before the last 7 digits

Tags: java

For example if I have a string that is a phone number

**1905**1112222 I would want 1905

or

**905**1112222 I would want 905

I need it to be able to work for any number of digits before *the last 7 digits*.

Comment: What if your string is less than 7 digits long? Are you expecting some error condition, or just to return `""`?

Comment: As long as it is 7 or more digits you can use `str.substring(0, str.length() - 7)`

Comment: its always 10 or more. its a phone number and there is a validation check so it will be 10+

Comment: @Nexevis yesss, bless your soul thats perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring` and go from the start of the `String` (AKA position `0`) to the length of the `String` minus `7`.

It will look like `str.substring(0, str.length() - 7)`.

**Test Code:**

```
 String str = "19051112222";
 System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 7));

 str = "9051112222";
 System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 7));
```

**Output:**

```
1905
905
```

Note that if the `String` is less than `7` characters, you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so if you expect that to be a possibility, you should convert this code into a method and check `if (str.length() < 7)`.

**Example Method:**

```
 public static String removeFinalSeven(String str) {
     if (str.length() < 7) {
         return ""; //return whatever you want to happen in this scenario
     }
     return str.substring(0, str.length() - 7);
 }
```